# JQuery Get method running only on one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well, i have a $.get method to get data from other page and load it to a div. But even with the .each, only one div is affected.
Here is the HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".post1").each(function() {
    var categlink = $(this).find(".post-area > a").attr("href");
    var pAvatar = $(this).find("img.postavatar");
    var pTTitle = $(this).find(".topictitle");
    var pContent = $(this).find(".postcontent");
    var pType = $(this).find("img.post-type");
    var pOwnerlink = $(this).find(".p-ownerlink");
    var pTime = $(this).find(".post-time");

    $.get(categlink, function(data) {
      var tLink = $(data).find(".main-content:nth-child(5) tr:first-child a.topictitle").attr("href");
      $.get(tLink, function(data) {
        var fAvatar = $(data).find(".post:first-child .user-basic-info > a > img").attr("src");
        pAvatar.attr("src", fAvatar);

        var fTopicTitle = $(data).find(".paged-head.clearfix > h1").text();
        pTTitle.text(fTopicTitle);

        var fTContent = $(data).find(".post:first-child .entry-content > div:first-child").html();
        pContent.html(fTContent);

        var fType = $(data).find(".post:first-child .posthead > h2 > img").attr("src");
        pType.attr("src", fType);

        var fOwner = $(data).find(".post:first-child h4.username > a > span > strong").text();
        pOwnerlink.text(fOwner);

        var fOwnerlink = $(data).find(".post:first-child h4.username > a").attr("href");
        pOwnerlink.attr("href", fOwnerlink);

        var fTTime = $(data).find(".post:first-child .posttime").text();
        pTime.text(fTTime);

        $(".postcontent img").each(function() {
          if ($(this).height() > 70) {
            $(this).addClass("imgresize");
            $('.main-forum').isotope({
              itemSelector: '.c-post',
              percentPosition: true,
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="c-post post1">
  <div class="post-info">
    <img class="postavatar">
    <div class="topictitle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="postcontent"></div>
  <div class="post-info2">
    <img class="post-type">
    <div class="post-owner">Por
      <a class="p-ownerlink"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-time"></div>
    <div class="post-area"><a href="{catrow.forumrow.U_VIEWFORUM}" title="{catrow.forumrow.FORUM_DESC}">{catrow.forumrow.FORUM_NAME}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="c-post post2">
  <div class="post-info">
    <img class="postavatar">
    <div class="topictitle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="postcontent"></div>
  <div class="post-info2">
    <img class="post-type">
    <div class="post-owner">Por
      <a class="p-ownerlink"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-time"></div>
    <div class="post-area"><a href="{catrow.forumrow.U_VIEWFORUM}" title="{catrow.forumrow.FORUM_DESC}">{catrow.forumrow.FORUM_NAME}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="c-post post3">
  <div class="post-info">
    <img class="postavatar">
    <div class="topictitle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="postcontent"></div>
  <div class="post-info2">
    <img class="post-type">
    <div class="post-owner">Por
      <a class="p-ownerlink"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-time"></div>
    <div class="post-area"><a href="{catrow.forumrow.U_VIEWFORUM}" title="{catrow.forumrow.FORUM_DESC}">{catrow.forumrow.FORUM_NAME}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Actually, my page has various .post1 divs, but only one of all is affected.
Thanks.

**EDIT**

So, the problem is: we cant use a $.get inside other $.get. The thing is: every .post1 has a link, that i call **tLink**. After getting tLink of the .post1, i need to run another $.get method using the tLink value to get info from other page. I've tried that, no sucess:

```js
function loadpostinfo() {
 $(".post1").each(function () {
  var categlink = $(this).find(".post-area > a").attr("href");
  var pAvatar = $(this).find("img.postavatar");
  var pTTitle = $(this).find(".topictitle");
  var pContent = $(this).find(".postcontent");
  var pType = $(this).find("img.post-type");
  var pOwnerlink = $(this).find(".p-ownerlink");
  var pTime = $(this).find(".post-time");

  $.get(categlink, function (data) {
   var tLink = $(data).find(".main-content:nth-child(5) tr:first-child a.topictitle").attr("href");
  });

  if (typeof tLink === "undefined") {
  } else {
   console.log("checked if tLink is valid");
   $.get(tLink, function (data) {
    console.log("running tLink get method");
    
    var fAvatar = $(data).find(".post:first-child .user-basic-info > a > img").attr("src");
    pAvatar.attr("src", fAvatar);

    var fTopicTitle = $(data).find(".paged-head.clearfix > h1").text();
    pTTitle.text(fTopicTitle);

    var fType = $(data).find(".post:first-child .posthead > h2 > img").attr("src");
    pType.attr("src", fType);

    var fOwner = $(data).find(".post:first-child h4.username > a > span > strong").text();
    pOwnerlink.text(fOwner);

    var fOwnerlink = $(data).find(".post:first-child h4.username > a").attr("href");
    pOwnerlink.attr("href", fOwnerlink);

    var fTTime = $(data).find(".post:first-child .posttime").text();
    pTime.text(fTTime);

    var fTContent = $(data).find(".post:first-child .entry-content > div:first-child").html();
    pContent.html(fTContent);

    setTimeout(alignposts, 5000);
   });
  }
 });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
 loadpostinfo();
});
```

How do i proceed?

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML? Why post the `.post2` and `.post3` divs instead of multiple `.post1`?

Comment: the result of $(".post1") is only one post, try to use $(".c-post")

Comment: @jan He says he has multiple `.post1` DIVs in the real HTML.

Comment: Barmar, its because the .post2 and .post3 will have other informations. Jan, i've tried that, and doenst work too. There is multiple .post1 on the page, its because i'm working on an existing website. http://i.imgur.com/a0EUfKS.png

Comment: Even if i run the code multiple times (by myself) in the page, nothing changes except the first .post1. Maybe there is a limit of $.get in the page? There is no log errors. I don't understand.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I don't read the last sentence.

Comment: what happens if you add a console.log() into the each function?

Comment: @jan sorry for the waiting. Well, if i put inside each, it show only one time the message. http://i.imgur.com/MzT4Du9.png

Comment: If i run a normal .each command, with nothing special, it works fine. Maybe the conflict is with the .get inside the .each? A JQuery bug? Someone can "translate" this to pure JavaScript? Just for testing.
http://i.imgur.com/GND8KwQ.png

Comment: Log the length of the query result: `console.log($(".post1").length)` if there is more then one result there must be an error inside your each.

Comment: @jan, actually, the result is 5. So, there is 5 .post1 in the page, and that's right. Like i said, i'm modifying a board system. All the .post1 divs are generated by server side on the page. I mean, i have just edited the HTML, the 4 other .post1 divs are generated in DOM by the severside.

Comment: Ok, i've found the problem: i cant use a $.get method inside other $.get. So, i need a way to first get a link that is inside each .post1, then i need to use that link in other $.get.

Comment: In think you can use nested $.get, there must be another problem, can you setup something like fiddler with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH MY GOSH, i'm the dumbest man in Earth!

**The problem:** only the first .post1 of page has content loaded. Each of then have a **categlink** url value, wich is used to get the **TLink** url value inside the categlink page. Then i use the TLink with $.get to load content inside this .post1 div.

**The fix:** only the categlink page from the first .post1 div actually has a TLink inside to use. The other ones was having no content matching my filters. So, this mess was all about data on server, and not JQuery or HTML.

Sorry for wasting your time, guys!
It's all fixed now, thanks!